# What technologies behind Web Push?

Tags: web, notifications, web-push, push-api

I was wondering what kind of technologies are behind Web Push, for example  https://goroost.com

How is that working? How to configure my server for Web Push? What should I look at?

Comment: Push API + Web Push protocol + Service Workers + Notifications API. I also wrote [this article](https://blog.pushpad.xyz/2022/03/web-push-notifications-standard-and-official-documentation/) which contains a simple explanation of each standard and a link to the official documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underlying technology is the [Push API](http://www.w3.org/TR/push-api/), combined with the [Notifications API](https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/)

You can read more about how to implement this yourself in [Google's developer docs](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notificatons-on-the-open-web). Note that currently push notifications are only supported in Google Chrome, but Microsoft and [Mozilla](https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2015/11/17/extending-the-webs-capabilities-in-firefox-and-beyond/) have said they will be implementing it soon.

Comment: for me it' only working in chrome. not in Opera. can you please let me know which version of Opera it working??

Comment: I don't think Opera works yet. They are working on it.

Comment: Works in Firefox since v44.0.

Comment: Opera is only supported on Android.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer for [WonderPush.com](https://www.wonderpush.com)

First, you need to sign up on WonderPush and declare your website.

Then, Copy/paste the following snippet before the closing `<body>` tag:

```js
<script>
(function(w, d, s, id, n){
  w[n] = w[n] || {q: [],
    init: function(o) {w[n].initOpts = o;},
    ready: function(c) {w[n].q.push(c);}};
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://cdn.by.wonderpush.com/sdk/1.1/wonderpush-loader.min.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(window, document, 'script', 'wonderpush-jssdk-loader','WonderPush'));

WonderPush.init({
  webKey: "[YOUR_WEBKEY]" // sign up for FREE to retrieve your web key
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, this is similar to GoRoost. Now my question is what's behind that? What would you look at if you want to implement your own?